# Remove xml namespace while transformation using xslt

Tags: xslt

I am transforming XML using XSLT and facing issue while namespace removal. If I remove xmlns it works fine.
Issue 1. It doesn't delete namespace from transformed XML
Issue 2. Doesn't implements other template I have in transformation.

My Input XML

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8" standalone="yes"?>
<Catalog xmlns="http://example.com">
    <Books>
        <book1>Wise1 Otherwise</book1>
        <book2>Great Expectations</book2>
    </Books>
    <library>
        <Name> Forsyth </Name>
        <city> Cumming </city>
    </library>

</Catalog>
```

Expected Result

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<Import>
   <Books>
      <book1>Wise1 Otherwise</book1>
      <book2>Great Expectations</book2>
   </Books>
   <elab>
       <Name> Forsyth </Name>
       <city> Cumming </city>
    </elab>
 </Import>
```

XSL

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>

<xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="@* | node()">
    <xsl:copy>
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:copy>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@xmlns">
<xsl:element name="{local-name()}" namespace="http://example.com">
    <xsl:apply-templates select="node() | @*"/>
</xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="library">
    <elab>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </elab>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="Catalog">
    <Import>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </Import>
</xsl:template>     

</xsl:stylesheet>
```

Comment: Namespace declarations are not attributes (even though they look the same) - they don't appear as attribute nodes in the XML tree and you can't match them with `<xsl:template match="@xmlns">`.  Again, as I said in my answer to your previous question, forget about the namespace declarations and just concentrate on creating elements and attributes that are in the right namespaces (or none, as the case may be) and the declarations will be sorted out by the serializer.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I think you are missing the namespace declaration in the XSLT templates to match elements:
This is my try:

```
<?xml version="1.0" encoding="UTF-8"?>
<xsl:stylesheet version="1.0" xmlns:xsl="http://www.w3.org/1999/XSL/Transform" xmlns:ns="http://example.com">
<xsl:output method="xml" indent="yes"/>
<xsl:strip-space  elements="*"/>

<xsl:template match="*">
    <xsl:element name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:apply-templates select="@* | node()"/>
    </xsl:element>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="@*">
    <xsl:attribute name="{local-name()}">
        <xsl:value-of select="."/>
    </xsl:attribute>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns:library">
    <elab>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </elab>
</xsl:template>

<xsl:template match="ns:Catalog">
    <Import>
        <xsl:apply-templates />
    </Import>
</xsl:template> 
</xsl:stylesheet>
```